# How do I return a &Path from a function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how to write proper Rust code, but I think I may be overestimating the power of the compiler's ability to understand the lifetimes of my objects. This is the code as I expected it to work:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::env;
use rusqlite::SqliteConnection;

struct SomeDatabase {
    conn: SqliteConnection,
}

impl SomeDatabase {
    fn getPath() -> &Path {
        let path = env::home_dir().unwrap();
        path.push("foo.sqlite3");
        path.as_path()
    }

    fn open() -> SomeDatabase {
        let path = SomeDatabase::getPath()
        SomeDatabase { conn: SqliteConnection::open(path).unwrap() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let db = SomeDatabase::open();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error about a missing lifetime specifier on `&Path`. I know if this took a reference parameter from the caller, it would take on the same lifetime as that reference has. Here though what I was expecting is that the lifetime would be attached to the variable I am assigning the result to.

I know lifetimes can be added explicitly, but I don't know how to apply them in this case. The compiler suggests trying the `'static` lifetime, but that doesn't make sense here as far as I know because the source of this function's return value isn't static.

Now, just to try to see what happened if I tried to compile the rest of the code, I changed the return type from `&Path` to `PathBuf` and called `as_path()` in `open()`. This caused the compiler to output these errors:

```
src\main.rs:22:30: 22:52 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `[u8]` [E0277]
src\main.rs:22         SomeDatabase { conn: SqliteConnection::open(path).unwrap() }
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:22:30: 22:52 note: `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
src\main.rs:22         SomeDatabase { conn: SqliteConnection::open(path).unwrap() }
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`SqliteConnection::open()` returns a `Result<SqliteConnection, SqliteError>` and the only field inside `SqliteConnection` is a `RefCell`, so I don't understand where this error about a byte array is coming from.

So, why aren't things working as I expect and what is the most Rusty way to write this code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your first case, you are creating a value and then trying to return a reference to it. But since you aren't storing that value anywhere, it gets destroyed after the function ends. If it was allowed, it'd be a use-after-free bug.

The reason it suggested returning a `&'static Path` is because the function isn't parameterized over any lifetimes, so the only lifetime you can be sure outlives anything that wants to use the return value would be `'static`.

You are correct that you need to return a `PathBuf` directly instead of an `&Path`.

I'm not quite sure why you are getting the `[u8]` sized errors.

You don't need to call "as_path()" at all. `SqliteConnection::open` takes a value that implements `AsRef<Path>` (`AsRef` is sort of like `Into`), and `PathBuf` does implement that trait.

Comment: I realize that in the first case I'm returning a reference to something created inside the function, but if I make getPath() a member function of SomeDatabase, the compiler is smart enough to hold the &Path until the instance of SomeDatabase goes out of scope. I'm asking if there's a way to tell the compiler that the lifetime of the reference belongs to the function that is calling the getPath() (in the case where getPath() is an associated function). It's lifetime code should be until the variable that holds the reference goes out of scope in open().

Comment: Also have to add that if I leave off as_path(), I get a mismatched types error: "expected '&_', found 'std::path::PathBuf' (expected &-ptr, found struct 'std::path::PathBuf')

Comment: @AustinWagner The variable `path` is defined in the body of the `getPath()` method, its lifetime ends at the end of the scope of this function body, unless you return it. There is no way to avoid this rule. In your case there is no alternative to returning the `PathBuf` for `getPath()` function.

Comment: @AustinWagner *if I make getPath a member function [...] the compiler hold[s] the &Path until the instance [...] goes out of scope* — This is [simply not true](http://is.gd/T7ZfJu). You have the same problem in that the **local variable** is dropped when the function returns because nothing owns it.

Comment: *`SqliteConnection::open` takes a value that implements* — note that [it actually takes](http://jgallagher.github.io/rusqlite/rusqlite/struct.SqliteConnection.html#method.open) **a reference to** a type that implements `AsRef`. I think this is likely why the sized errors are occurring. This seems like a strange decision on the part of the library...

Comment: @Shepmaster I must have done something wrong when I tested changing getPath to a member function, but it appears you are right. My assumption that it is possible to have the compiler lift the variable into the scope of the caller when returning a reference was obviously wrong. I'm marking this as the accepted answer since the answer and the comments contain enough information to make it useful to others with the same misunderstandings.